# Secure Apache PHP installation: Using the right user:group

Tags: linux, security, permissions, apache-http-server, php

i want to "perfectly" protect my apache PHP installation on a linux server. In the history, i had problems with script-virues / exploids, so it needs to be a "secure" solution.

My current solution:

- Every webspace has an own user, with its own user groups (for example: user1:user1).
- Apache runs under http:http
- PHP is running via fast cgi and **SuexecUserGroup** user1:user1
- The webspace directory is owned by user1:http, for initialiy setting the chmods: sett all to 0 and than chmod u+rwX,g+rX. Thats means, Owner(user1) has full access, Group has read access, others have no access.

This works fine and is secure...but it will not work when:

- Creating a file via PHP
- uploading a file via FTP.

Than the file will created as user1:user1. This is (normally) corret. But than has apache (http:http) no access anymore.

One workarround "could" be:
Keep all files as user1:user1, but run apache as root. But, this is not very secure...

So, what could be a good solution? Of course, i rad dozens of blogs, but every solution would have another problem.

Comment: If you know where the uploads are, you could have a cron job or script running (likely hooked to inotify), that you could use to modify the permissions of the uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution may be to add Apache user (http) to each user group:

```
adduser http user1
adduser http user2
adduser http user3
etc...
```

You'll need a little script to do this, but it give Apache the needed access most of the time.

Alternative / better solution

See if the FTP server has an option for default group for created files and setup PHP with `SuexecUserGroup user1:http`

Comment: Adding the user "http" to all webspace groups, seems to work. I will test it now more carefully, but i think this was the solution.

I thought, apache would not change his "logged in" group member ship via "newgrp user1" automaticly.

The "SuexecUserGroup user1:http"-Solution is a bad solution. I tried it before, and the problem was, all php scripts have access to other webspaces than. Or do you mean, the user1 should still have group user1, but apache should try run him under user1:http, is this possible? (running a user in a group, that he does not belong to).

Comment: I believe it is possible to run a user in a group he doesn't belong to, but i've not tried it. I'm not sufficiently familiar with SuexecUserGroup for giving you a definitive answer.